# git/GitHub property configuration

Tags: java, git, authentication, configuration, github

I am learning git and have found a great series of articles at http://gitimmersion.com/. However there are a few questions surrounding git "properties" that I'm still not quite understanding.

1. Properties like `user.name` and `user.email`...where are these configured? The `.gitconfig` file? Is this where all git properties are stored?
2. What SSL/auth properties do I need to set for pulling/pushing changes to a **private** GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git properties are  stored inside the `.git/config` file. Is a simple text file so you can look at at it to see what informations it contain. Other infos are writtend in the files inside the `.git/info/` directory. These files are relative to only the single repo.

When you set a property with the `--global` flag (like your username / email) the property gets written in your personal git preference, and so it affects all the repositories. In *nix systems the file that stores global preferences is `~/.gitconfig` in windows 7 is `C:\Users\YourLogin\.gitconfig`.

Regarding the second part of your question, read the GitHub help pages [Setup git with GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git), you will find all the informations you need.

For a private GitHub repository I don't think that procedure will change, you still need a `username` and a `password`. As far as I know you will configure the repo as a private repo using the GitHub web-interface.
I can find only a reference on [How to make a pubblic repository private](https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-public-repository-private).

Comment: Thanks @Atropo (+1) - however I had already found that same exact GitHub link before writing this question. If you read it carefully, it really only applies to public GitHub repos. But for private GitHub repos, there are additional authentication-centric properties (and perhaps other attributes/settings/etc.) that you need to set locally.  **Otherwise, anybody would be able to pull/push to/from a private GitHub repo so long as they knew the clone URL.** Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again @Atropo (+1 again) - one last followup: you mention that I will need to set a `username` and a `password`. For `username`, I assume you mean setting `user.name` and `user.email` inside the `.git/config` file of my repo, yes? But what about `password`? Thanks again!

Comment: The password is the one you've use when signing to GitHub. You'll be asked to enter it when `pushing` to your `repo`. You can ask git to `cache` it as explained on the GitHub help page.